# Include changelog in dropfolder

Tags: tfs

I have a customized build process that sets the build name to the current version, updates the FileAssemblyVersion, drops to two different folders, and removes all unessential files from the drop folders, and I'm feeling that I'm starting to get the hang of custom actions and the workflows now.

So now I want to include a changelog in my drop folder; the Changeset comments. Either only the Changesets associated with this build, but possibly all changesets from a given changeset (such as a version number change, or another event).

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Codeplex project TFSChangeLog can help you. From a command line you can create a XML file. Using XSLT you can create an output file of your choice.

> http://tfschangelog.codeplex.com

Comment: Great. I'll take a look.